# How to combine two columsn/rows of a matrix in numpy by summing values?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm using numpy and am trying to figure out an issue I'm having with matrices. Say I have a 3 x 3 matrix and want to transform it into a 2 x 2 matrix through summing the first and second columns and rows together. For instance, given:

```
import numpy as np 
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
m = np.array(a)
```

Displaying m yields:

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

I want to first sum the first and second rows to get:

```
array([5, 7, 9],
      [7, 8, 9])
```

And then sum the first and second columns to get:

```
array([12, 9],
      [15, 9])
```

This is just a toy example, but in practice I have a 24 x 24 matrix that I want to slim down to a 4 x 4 matrix. I have 4 different lists of integers, each list representing different indices in the overall 24 x 24 matrix. What I want to do is iterate through each list and combine the rows and columns whose indices are found in the lists. For instance if one list has the indices [3,4,5], I want to iterate through this list and combine rows/columns 3, 4 and 5. Any idea how this can be done in numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using integer array indexing and the "axis" option in numpy's sum. For example, starting with:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
list0 = [0,1,2]
list1 = [3]
```

The initial array is

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
   [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
   [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
   [12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

The lists of indices can be used to "select" only the rows you want from an array. For example,

```
a[list0,:]
```

is

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Also, rows of an array can be added together using the "axis=0" argument in numpy's sum, and the result is a 1D array. For example,

```
np.sum(a[list0,:],axis=0)
```

results in

```
array([12, 15, 18, 21])
```

Summing like this we can build the row-summed array row by row:

```
b = np.zeros((2,a.shape[1]))
b[0,:] = np.sum(a[list0,:],axis=0)
b[1,:] = np.sum(a[list1,:],axis=0)
```

The resulting array is

```
array([[12., 15., 18., 21.],
   [12., 13., 14., 15.]])
```

A similar thing can be done for the columns, but with "axis=1" to add the columns:

```
c = np.zeros((2,2))
c[:,0] = np.sum(b[:,list0],axis=1)
c[:,1] = np.sum(b[:,list1],axis=1)
```

which yields the 2x2 array:

```
array([[45., 21.],
       [39., 15.]])
```

If you want to do it in a more compact way, you could loop over the lists and combine them into a single array using vstack:

```
idx_lists = [list0, list1]
b = np.vstack([np.sum(a[idx_lists[n],:],0) for n in range(2)])
```

Stacking together the columns is a little trickier, since sum returns a 1D array, which is treated as a row. One solution is to vertically stack the rows together and take a transpose at the end:

```
c = np.vstack([np.sum(b[:,idx_lists[n]],1) for n in range(2)]).T
```